# Doctorize Nextjs React Application

Tags: reactjs, docker, next.js

I have an SSR Nextjs application written with React. I am trying to use docker with this application but i am stuck to launch the app with docker. I created a Dockerfile and docker-compose

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine as base
RUN apk add --no-cache g++ make py3-pip libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
EXPOSE 3000

FROM base as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM node:18-alpine AS production
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./

ENV NODE_ENV=production
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ENV=production
ENV PORT=3001
RUN npm ci --only=production
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3001
USER node

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]

FROM base as dev
ENV NODE_ENV=development
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD npm run dev
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    image: nextjs_zaahib
    build:
      context: ./
      target: production
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app/.next
    ports:
      - "3001:80"
```

As you see i mapped port 80 on container to port 3001 on host, however when running docker compose up -d i am unable to access it on browser on http://localhost:3001 it gives unreachable

Comment: It looks like you're exposing port 80 and mapping port 3001. Your application is accessible at http://localhost or exposed container port at 80 and accessed at http://localhost:3001. flip the port `80:3001`

Comment: The Dockerfile looks like your container is serving on port 3000 or 3001 (why change this for the two different build stages?) and that port number needs to be the second `ports:` number as well.

Comment: Are you sure that you're "Doctorizing" something or rather "dockerize"?

Answer (score 2):

```
80 on container to port 3001 on host, however when running docker compose up -d i am unable to access it on browser on http://localhost:3001
```

The issue here is the "from/to" relationship.

Your app is listening on port 3001(why actually? you can use 3000 and there's probably no need to expose the base layer). So that is the container port. If you want to reach the container from the host and get traffic to, you need to map a host port to it so that your request goes something like this.

You --> host port --> container port.

For port 80 on host and 3001 in the container:

You --> 80 --> 3001

Now this also needs to be reflected in the compose file so your port section needs to change to this:

```yaml
    ports:
      - "80:3001"
```